# Does a Hazmat Vest make your soldier immune to Chryssalid poison?

Tags: xcom-2

[Hazmat vest](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Hazmat_Vest) grant your soldiers immunity to poison, but does that also apply to the special poison that Chryssalids use?

I know you can cure Chryssalid poison with a Medkit (just like normal poison), but I wasn't sure if it worked the same way for Hazmat vests.

Comment: Hazmat suit? Is that an armor utility item?

Comment: @DCShannon yes.

Comment: What's different about the chryssalid poison that makes you think it won't work?

Comment: @DCShannon the fact that it has a special name, I don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the source files provided with the mod tools, Chryssalid attacks inflict a 'ParthenogenicPoison' effect, one feature of which is dealing poison damage over time.

Hazmat vests provide both immunity to poison damage *and* a separate explicit immunity to the ParthenogenicPoison, so **they will protect you against Chryssalid poison***.

*Or, at least, they're intended to: I'm not 100% sure that there are no bugs that might affect this (though I *have* checked that the Hazmat-vests-don't-block-acid bug *doesn't* affect it).

Comment: Related: I confirmed that medkits remove Chryssalid poison this morning on two different soldiers.

Answer (score -1):

Hazmat suits should only protect you against fire, gas and acid according to their description, but there currently seems to be a bug where the acid immunity doesn't actually work.

Given how the item description doesn't mention Chryssalid poison, it seems highly unlikely that it gives you immunity.

Comment: The description says "fire, acid or poison", not gas. Doesn't gas inflict poison damage? Since it says poison, I would expect it to defend against poison.